# pycharm auto unstashing changes after rebase

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

After rebase (git plugin) Pycharm has unstash last stashed changeset. It causes merge conflicted files etc.
I did not find any related settings to configure it.
How can this be turned off?

Comment: workaround is to use git in terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In main menu VCS -> Update Project

In this area, specify the method to save your changes while cleaning your working tree before update. The changes will be restored after the update is completed. The available options are:
Using Stash(git native) and Using Shelve(Idea native)

So using shelve will avoid issues with stashed data (I am not using shelve for my files so no conflicts)